# vertices - edges - faces icon left upper corner in edit mode is gone! Blender 2,93.4

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

hope one can help me here. The 3 vertices, edges and faces icons on the left upper corner disappeared. I m working on a Mac Laptop so I do not know how to use 1,2,3 without changing the perspective.

New to this, maybe someone knows how to bring the icons back.
Many thanks!

[image: vertices, edges nor faces icon]

Comment: Are the icons along the bottom? A new feature made it so that the UI element containing those buttons (and more) can be flipped to the bottom of the screen if the user prefers.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are editing a curve, not a mesh.
A curve is made of points, not vertices / edges / faces, that's why you can't see the buttons in this case.

Comment: pfff haha...yes thanks! Took me 1h to figure this out.

Comment: please accept the answer then :)